# Truncation erros in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Try to calculate:
>
> [image]
>
> by storing 1/N and X as float variable. Which result do you get for N=10000, 100000 and 1000000?
>
> Now try to use double variables. Does it change outcome?

In order to do this I wrote this code:

```
#TRUNCATION ERRORS

import numpy as np               #library for numerical calculations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #library for plotting purposes

x = 0

n = 10**6

X = []
N = []

for i in range(1,n+1):
  x = x + 1/n

  item = float(x)
  item2 = float(n)
  X.append(item)
  N.append(item2)
 
plt.figure()                    #block for plot purpoes
plt.plot(N,X,marker=".")
plt.xlabel('N')
plt.ylabel('X')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image: my output]

This is wrong because the output should be like that (showed in the lecture):

[image: Expected output]

Comment: "float variables" and "double variables" are not a thing in Python. Variables don't have types. And floats are 64 bit.

Comment: Ok, thanks. 

Other than that, how can I get the correct output using python?

Comment: Sure, i did it now.

Comment: Why do you have `item2 = float(1/i)`? I don't see anything like that in the instructions.

Comment: It is an error, my fault. I need to store ```1\n```...

Comment: @KellyBundy because of limited precision of float (using c++ or other language different from python), but this can't happen in python...so so I expect a constant graph at 1 without deviation.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ps:  "y" it is a "X" written in bad way...

Comment: Why are you appending `1/n` to the `N` array?

Comment: The sense is that (for example using c++): 

Numerically, one start to see deviation if using single precision (round-off error) but with double precision this is not possibile (like in python) and we see always 1.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi because i want to store ```1/n```. Maybe i did it in the wrong way.

Comment: @KellyBundy `sum(1/N)` from `i = 1 to N` is just `N * 1/N`, which should be `1`. The objective of the exercise is to demonstrate errors in floating-point math because that result will not be exactly one.

Comment: Right, The objective is this. @PranavHosangadi

Comment: @J.Snowden first, you want to plot `N` on the x-axis, but you're actually plotting `1/N`. Second, you aren't calculating the expression you think you're calculating. You need to calculate `sum_{i=1..N}(1/N)` which is `1/N + 1/N + ... + 1/N` repeated `N` times. It looks like you're calculating `sum_{i=1..N}(1/i)`

Comment: I have corrected the first point of your comment, I am now graphing ``n`` and not ``1/n``. 

As for the second point, I did the math by hand and it looks like the function I want to calculate ```sum_{i=1..N}(1/N)``` is equal to ```x = x + 1/n``` or am I in error?

Comment: You're wrong about the function you want to calculate being equal to what you are calculating. Do a couple of iterations by hand and see if that's what you actually want. (spoiler alert: it's not)

Comment: By hands:

i=1 is x = 0 +1/3, 
i=2 is x= 1/3+1/3,
i=3 is x=1/3+1/3+1/3. 

I'm not understanding where is the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to plot `N` on the x-axis, but you're actually plotting `1/N`.

Second, you aren't calculating the expression you think you're calculating. It looks like you're calculating `sum_{i=1..N}(1/i)`.
You need to calculate `sum_{i=1..N}(1/N)` which is `1/N + 1/N + ... + 1/N` repeated `N` times. In other words, you want to calculate `N * 1 / N`, which should be equal to `1`. Your exercise is showing you that it won't be when you use floating-point math, because [reasons.](//docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

To do this correctly, let's first define a list of values for `N`

```
Nvals = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
```

Let's define a function that will calculate our summation for *a single value* of `N`:

```
def calc_sum(N):
    total = 0
    for i in range(N):
        total += 1 / N
    return total
```

Next, let's create an empty list of `Xvals` and fill it up with the calculated sum for each N

```
Xvals = []
for N in Nvals:
    Xvals.append(calc_sum(N))
```

or, as a listcomprehension:

```
Xvals = [calc_sum(N) for N in Nvals]
```

Now we get this value of Xvals:

```
[1.0,
 0.9999999999999999,
 1.0000000000000007,
 1.0000000000000007,
 0.9999999999999062,
 0.9999999999980838,
 1.000000000007918]
```

Clearly, they are not all equal to `1`.

You can increase the number of values in `Nvals` to get a denser plot, but the idea is the same.

Now pay attention to what [@khelwood](/users/3890632/khelwood) said in their comment:

> "float variables" and "double variables" are not a thing in Python. Variables don't have types. And floats are 64 bit

Python floats are all 64-bit floating-point numbers, so you can't do your exercise in python. If you used a language like C or C++ that actually has 32-bit `float` and 64-bit `double` types, you'd get something like this:

[Try it online](https://onlinegdb.com/m39XGNmSE)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

float calc_sum_f(int N) {
    float total = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        total += ((float)1 / N);
    return total;
}

double calc_sum_d(int N) {
    double total = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        total += ((double)1 / N);
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    int Nvals[7] = { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 };

    std::cout << "N\tdouble\tfloat" << std::endl;
    
    for (int ni = 0; ni < 7; ni++) {
        int N = Nvals[ni];
        double x_d = calc_sum_d(N);
        float x_f = calc_sum_f(N);
        
        std::cout << N << "\t" << x_d << "\t" << x_f << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
N       double   float
1       1        1
10      1        1
100     1        0.999999
1000    1        0.999991
10000   1        1.00005
100000  1        1.00099
1000000 1        1.00904
```

Here you can see that 32-bit `float`s don't have enough precision beyond a certain value of `N` to accurately calculate `N * 1 / N`. There's no reason the plot should look like your hand-drawn plot, because there's no reason it will *decrease* consistently as we can evidently see here.

---

Using `numpy` <sup>Thanks for the suggestion [@Kelly](/users/12671057/kelly-bundy)</sup> to get 32-bit and 64-bit floating point types in python, we can similarly define two functions:

```
def calc_sum_64(N):
    c = np.float64(0)
    one_over_n = np.float64(1) / np.float64(N)
    for i in range(N):
        c += one_over_n
    return c

def calc_sum_32(N):
    c = np.float32(0)
    one_over_n = np.float32(1) / np.float32(N)
    for i in range(N):
        c += one_over_n
    return c
```

Then, we find `Xvals_64` and `Xvals_32`

```
Nvals = [10**i for i in range(7)]
Xvals_32 = [calc_sum_32(N) for N in Nvals]
Xvals_64 = [calc_sum_64(N) for N in Nvals]
```

And we get:

```
Xvals_32 = [1.0, 1.0000001, 0.99999934, 0.9999907, 1.0000535, 1.0009902, 1.0090389]

Xvals_64 = [1.0,
 0.9999999999999999,
 1.0000000000000007,
 1.0000000000000007,
 0.9999999999999062,
 0.9999999999980838,
 1.000000000007918]
```

I haven't vectorized my numpy code to make it easier for you to understand what's going on, but Kelly shows a great way to vectorize it to speed up the calculation:

`sum(1/N) from  i = 1 to N` is `(1 / N) + (1 / N) + (1 / N) + ... {N times}` , which is an array of `N` ones, divided by `N` and then summed. You could write the `calc_sum_32` and `calc_sum_64` functions like so:

```
def calc_sum_32(N):
    return (np.ones((N,), dtype=np.float32) / np.float32(N)).sum()

def calc_sum_64(N):
    return (np.ones((N,), dtype=np.float64) / np.float64(N)).sum()
```

You can then call these functions for every value of `N` you care about, and get a plot that looks like so, which shows the result oscillating about 1 for `float32`, but barely any oscillation for `float64`:

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks @pranav.

Just a clarification, now i'm trying to plot the result of your code, in this way:

``` plt.scatter(Xvals,Nvals,marker=".")``` 

but i see a stranger plot....

ps: I'm studyng your c code, i don't know this language

Comment: @PranavHosangadi how did you get your plot? (last image)

Comment: I ran that code for every `N` in the range, with a step of 10k so that I wouldn't be waiting forever, and plotted what I got. @J.Snowden

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you. Last question for this topic : Can you arrange your Final Python code like the C one in the online editor? 

I am having some difficulty in reproducing it in my compiler.

Comment: Btw the vectorized way seems to give more accurate results. I guess it doesn't do a simple sum from front to back but splits it into parts and computes them in parallel and then adds up the partial sums or something like that? Or uses a more accurate type for the calculation and converts the result to the worse type at the end?

Comment: @J.Snowden the final python code is right there. Copy the `calc_sum_*` functions. Then copy the list comprehensions that calculate `Nvals` and `Xvals_*`. That's it. I used `plt.plot(Nvals, Xvals_32)` and the same for `Xvals_64`. What trouble are you having with reproducibility?

Comment: @KellyBundy it's very possible. I'm not an expert on the inner workings of numpy, and it'd probably depend on the libraries the backend uses, but it's very possible that your second hypothesis is correct.

Comment: Found a [discussion about sum vs numpy.sum](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8632), which mentions "pairwise summation", which is also mentioned in the [numpy.sum documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html).

Comment: My code: https://pastebin.com/11v8uqBJ

The output is much different from your... @pranav

Comment: @J.Snowden well _yes_, I didn't plot at just `10**1, 10**2, ..., 10**6`. As I said in a previous comment: *I ran that code for every N in the range, with a step of 10k so that I wouldn't be waiting forever, and plotted what I got.* `Nvals = list(range(1, 10**6+1, 10000))` It's pretty evident from the plot that there are more than 7 values of `N`, isn't it?

Comment: Right, Now i understand!